# call ngOndestroy of a component before calling logout button from shared Header component

Tags: javascript, angular

When I click on shared header logout button of my application from a specific component the logout function is first called then the component ngOnDestroy is called.

How to call ngOnDestroy before calling logout function.

```
header.component.ts
  logout() {
     //CALLING FIRST
  }

specific.component.ts
 ngOnDestroy(){
   //CALLING AFTER LOGOUT
 }


header.component.html
<logout button>

<specific.component.html
<header></header>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually that is right behaviour, but you can try to use something like this:

in parent which includes both header and specific:

```
show: boolean = true;

onLogout() {
    this.show = false;
}
```

in header...ts:

```
@Output() onLogout: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

logout() {
    this.onLogout.emit('');
    // your logout operations;
}
```

in parent...html:

```
<specific *ngIf="show" ...>
```

destroy of specific component might before logout operations in this way;
P.S. haven't try this, just a suggestion